# Will my buffer used by all connections?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, shared-ptr

I have a main which creates an `io_service` and passes them to an instance of `TcpServer`.

`TcpServer` has a member `std::array<char, 8192> m_buffer`. It has 4 methods: the constructor, startAccept, *handleAccept* and handleRead.
The constructor only initializes some members and calls startAccept.

startAccept creates a shared pointer of `TcpConnection` which extends `std::enable_shared_from_this<TcpConnection`. After that start accept calls m_acceptor.async_accept and binds the accept to the handleAccept method mentioned before.

And this is my *handleAccept* method. It calls async_read_some with the boost::asio::buffer which uses the member variable declared in TcpServer.

```
void TcpServer::handleAccept(std::shared_ptr<TcpConnection> newConnection, const boost::system::error_code &error)
{
    if (!error) {
        //newConnection->start();

        std::cout << "Accepting new connection" << std::endl;
        newConnection->getSocket().async_read_some(
            boost::asio::buffer(m_buffer),
            boost::bind(&TcpServer::handleRead, this, newConnection, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)
        );
    }

    startAccept();
}
```

I am not sure, but if there are multiple connections, all of them will use the same buffer object, right? And they will probably overwrite it, won't they?

Comment: It depends on the exact implementation of `buffer`, `buffer(m_buffer)` means "*create new `buffer` from `m_buffer`*" but who knows what does that mean in practice, use it's storage? copy it's contents? etc.

Comment: buffer is boost::asio::buffer. I have a `using boost::asio::buffer;` in my file. I edited my original question. So... Will that change anything about my problem?

Comment: The buffer should be in `TCPConnection`, not in `TCPServer`. A server only has an accept loop. It doesn't need a buffer, but every connection does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146083/discussion-between-sehe-and-luk32).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all connections will use same buffer, that is defined in `TcpServer`. You actually should store buffer in connection, rather than in server.

`boost::asio::buffer` will use [that overload](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer/overload17.html). So, data from read will be stored to your `m_buffer`. You should store your `buffer` in connection, or use some synchronization (i.e. some boolean flag, like `is_in_read`, but that is bad idea).

Comment: OK good advice. I'll put them in the TcpConnection. Thank you for your fast answer.